# Where in Arkham Asylum are the plans for Arkham City?

Tags: batman-arkham-asylum, batman-arkham-city

I was just [reading on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Arkham_City) about the forthcoming [Batman: Arkham City](http://www.batmanarkhamcity.org/), and it seems the developers were planning the sequel before the original was even released.  There is a secret room somewhere in Arkham Asylum containing Quincy Sharp's plans to build Arkham City.

**Where in the game can I find these secret plans?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The plans are in the back of Quincy Sharp's office. [GameInformer](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/features/archive/2010/08/09/arkham-asylums-secret-room.aspx) has a video walkthrough describing how to see the plans for yourself.

Answer (score 5):

It's in Quincey Sharp's Office, when you walk in. Go to the left and go to the wall. You need to use all three Explosive Gels to knock it down